# Browser Refresh Issue Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Hello everyone :)**

I'm starting with angularJs but I'm facing an issue with a directive I have created.

The code is working but when I change something on the directives html code/template and then refresh the page in the browser nothing change.

The only way I have to see the changes is to restart the browser in private/incognito mode.

I don't really know how to solve this issue.

Thanks for the help ;p.

Comment: Maybe some browser cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the browser is using cached version.

In chrome:

1. open developer tools
2. Select 'Network' tab
3. You'll find a checkbox called 'Disable cache', tick that

This will make sure nothing will be cached while the developer tool is open

Comment: Thank you guys, It's working when the developer tools is open but not when Its closed, it's annoying :/

Answer (score 0):

fyi

if the developer tools are open and refresh the page, the cache of chrome get cleared.

That's an option and I think it is active.

greets Christian